# Trouble with MySql statement with multiple selects

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am trying to get this statement to work:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    sakai.SAKAI_REALM AS sr
WHERE
    sr.REALM_KEY = (SELECT DISTINCT
            srrf.REALM_KEY
        FROM
            sakai.SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN AS srrf
        WHERE
            srrf.ROLE_KEY = 51);
```

But I am getting MySql error 1242, Subquery returns more than 1 row. I do know that it will return more than one row (it should return 7) but is there a way to get this query to work? I wouldn't doubt I'm using the wrong syntax.

I am trying to find all SAKAI_REALMS that have an existing value in the subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change `=` to `in`, that basically says for values in the set returned from the sub-query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
sakai.SAKAI_REALM AS sr
WHERE
sr.REALM_KEY in (SELECT DISTINCT
        srrf.REALM_KEY
    FROM
        sakai.SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN AS srrf
    WHERE
        srrf.ROLE_KEY = 51);
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it. The = allows only 1 value while the in allows multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Using a join you could do the following:

```
SELECT sr.*
FROM sakai.SAKAI_REALM AS sr
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT srrf.REALM_KEY
  FROM sakai.SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN AS srrf
  WHERE srrf.ROLE_KEY = 51
) m ON sr.REALM_KEY = m.REALM_KEY
```

Or, if the sub query could possibly return more than one record then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM sakai.SAKAI_REALM AS sr
WHERE sr.REALM_KEY IN 
(
  SELECT srrf.REALM_KEY
  FROM sakai.SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN AS srrf
  WHERE srrf.ROLE_KEY = 51
);
```

Or, force it to only return one record with `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM sakai.SAKAI_REALM AS sr
WHERE sr.REALM_KEY = 
(
  SELECT srrf.REALM_KEY
  FROM sakai.SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN AS srrf
  WHERE srrf.ROLE_KEY = 51
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the different options! They helped explain the different ways.